# Standard Criteria Sharing or Apex Sharing Needed?

Tags: apex, formula-field, sharing-rule

I have child object that hangs off the standard Contact object.  I am wanting to create a criteria-based sharing rule that uses 3 or 4 fields on the child object to determine if the Contact record should be shared.

Can this be achieved with out-of-the-box criteria-based sharing rules or is apex sharing required to do this?

I am hoping to avoid creating formula fields on the Contact or rolling up data to the Contact if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you're looking for is not possible with Criteria-Based Sharing Rules, at least not with the constraints you've listed. You must have the data on the Contact record in order to use this feature. Therefore, you're stuck with Apex Sharing instead.